# Check difference in file structure

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync

On Linux I've done a rsync syncing supposedly everything in /home to /backup. Both of these disk are the same size, but after the sync du -h shows around 50G difference. I want to know what the 50G difference is. What's the best way to check it?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a possible reason: If /backup wasn't empty and you didn't use rsync's `--delete` option then /backup should be larger than /home.

Comment: Hi I did have the --delete option on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd /backup ; find . -type f -printf '%P %s' | sort > backupcontent.txt`.

Repeat for `/home`, then diff the resulting files.

`%P %s` are file name relative to the `/home` and `/backup` folders, and size. Add any attributes you care about.

This method assumes that a file that exists at both locations and is the same size (and other relevant attributes of your choice) is identical. You could additionally get file checksums using `-exec`.

Comment: Thanks it works. It turns out that there are files not in the ascii encoding that's not being backed up.